# Handling dynamically generated html elements using jquery mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Im developing a mvc5 application. In a view, using jquery i generate html elements(dropdownlists and textboxes) dynamically.

View briefly

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Item"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.MainGrpId, new SelectList(ViewBag.mnGrpList, "MainGroupId", "MainGroupName"), " Select a MainGroup", new { Class = "form-  control", title = "", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" })

    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SubGrpId, new SelectList(ViewBag.sbGrpList, "SubGroupId", "SubGroupName"), " Select a SubGroup", new { Class = "form-control", title = "", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" })

    <div id="ss" class="col-md-6">

    </div>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.ItemName, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = " Item Name", TextMode = "MultiLine2", onkeyup = "return validateChar(this)", style = "width:175px;height:25px;" })

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" /> 
}
```

Jquery

```
var ss = $('#ss');
$('#SubGrpId').change(function () {
    $('#ss').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FillItem", "Item")', // dont hard code your url's
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { MnId: $('#MainGrpId').val(), SbId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
        success: function (y) {
            $.each(y, function (l, u) {
                // add the label
                var label = u.Name;
                var name = 'Field' + l;
                var label = $('<label></label>').text(label).attr('for', name);
                ss.append(label);
                if (u.Options.length==0) {
                    // There is only one item and its for generating a textbox
                    var input = $('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', id: name, name: name });
                    ss.append(input);
                } else {
                    // Its a select
                    var select = $('<select></select>').attr({ id: name, name: name });
                    // add each option
                    $.each(u.Options, function (i, option) {
                        select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.Value).text(option.Text));
                    })
                    ss.append(select);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("something wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

ItemViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public int MainGrpId { get; set; }

    public int SubGrpId { get; set; }

    public string Field0 { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }

}
```

Altogether number of dynamically generated ddls+textboxes are equal or less than 6. What i want to do is when user selects an item from a ddl or enters a value to a texbox, the value in that particular element(string) should be shown in 'ItemName' textbox. User can go on adding like that. Each added value(string) should be shown separated by a space in 'ItemName' textbox.

Futher every ddl and textbox(only dynamically generated ones-Field0, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, ) should get enabled one by one(one after another) allowing user to select(ddls)/enter(textboxes). But im struggling to develop the correct jquery function for this whole scenario. Pls help me with this. Thanks!